# Почему возникает ошибка: Cannot open include file: 'QImage': No such file or directory?

Tags: c++, qt

QtCreator не видит библиотеку QImage, хотя сам мне её предлагает в списке.

.pro

```
QT += gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QImage>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QImage image("D:/Qt Sources/QtConsole/Images/1_1.png");

    std::cout << image.width();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Ошибка в консоли:

> D:\Qt Sources\QtConsole\main.cpp:2: ошибка: C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'QImage': No such file or directory

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "не видит библиотеку"?

Comment: Копируйте текст ошибок в вопрос в виде текста, а не скриншотов. И по ошибке выходит, что по тому пути картинки нет. Еще, предположительно проблема с слешами, тогда сделайте так: `QImage image("D:\\Qt Sources\\QtConsole\\Images\\1_1.png");`

Comment: Не помогает....

Comment: Пишите, @<ник>, когда комментируете кому-то, например @gil9red  :) Значит, у вас или в пути ошибка или по тому пути нет той картинки (что по сути одно и то же)

Comment: Уберите `console` из `CONFIG` в pro-файле.

Comment: @gil9red "Cannot open include file" он не может открыть именно include file

Comment: @älёxölüt Не помогло

Comment: Clean, run qmake, rebuild делали после всех изменений?

Comment: @älёxölüt а как это сделать, я просто нажимаю ctrl + b, ctrl + r

Comment: Неа, он не может найти файл по пути, ваш код вызывает этот конструктор [QImage::QImage(const QString &fileName, const char *format = nullptr)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-8), а там строка с путем. Проверьте путь: откройте проводник и вставьте в адресную строку `D:/Qt Sources/QtConsole/Images/1_1.png` должен открыться тот файл

Comment: Я поменял Kit на MinGW 32bit и у меня всё закомпилилось, странно...

Comment: @gil9red на картинке чётко видно проблему с невозможностью подключить заголовочный файл. До конструкторов дело не доходит.

Comment: @älёxölüt, точно... был не прав :)

Comment: Может что-то не так с MCVS 2017 64bit? Хотя что там может быть не так, он же только не давно скачан

Comment: Ошибка в 'QCoreApplication'. Поменяйте на 'QGuiApplication' и попробуйте. Warning: Qt requires that a QGuiApplication object exists before any paint devices can be created. Paint devices access window system resources, and these resources are not initialized before an application object is created.

Comment: @KirillPukhov, по проблеме — всё ещё звучит так буд-то `qmake` не запускал после изменения *.pro файла... можешь попробовать ручками снести все сборочные файлы...